# Multiuser access to a home server

Tags: vnc, x11-forwarding, multi-user

We want to configure a powerfull home machine (32 GB RAM, Core i7-10700K, RTX 3090 GPU) so that 3 users can connect to it from their laptops (optionaly also with UHD monitor) and simulaneously run their own GUI and tasks (machine learning, Blender). We want to move the computer to attic where it can produce heat and noise. No keyboard and monitor will be attached to it, only LAN cable. A home server booted via WOL.

So far we suceeded with installing Ubuntu 22 with proprietary Nvidia (for CUDA) driver on Wayland (for fractional scaling). We have troubles with remote access.

1. VNC . Remmina client can connect to Gnome remote desktop sharing.
   1A: It works only for one user at a time. Second user steals session of the first user.
   1B: Scaling of native 4K resolution to FHD on some laptops does not seem optimal.
   1C: No sound is transferred.
2. X Forwarding.
   2A: Running an app with ssh -X is so slow that a warning messsage is displayed. After hitting Wait button every app always freezes.
   2B: Most applications do not work at all (many various erros in terminal). Possibly Wayland related issue?

Do you have any pointers to issues 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B? Is VNC preferable over X forwarding? Is there some third options how to achieve our goal?  We are rather new to Linux and want to ditch Windows.

Thank you!
Martin Zeman

Comment: VNC: did you set `unset SESSION_MANAGER` and `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in `.vnc/xstartup`?

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So do you mean Ubuntu Core 22?  as it's a different system to Ubuntu 22.04 with the far more widely used *year.month* systems (22.04) available for both desktop & server use, where as 22 is intended for *headless* operation only (not desktop use).